# how to set onclicklistener on cardview with data from database?

Tags: java, android

The app has a recycler view which has card to display the data from the database. i want to let the user be able to click the card and it would show more details.The card has info of name,type and location only and it less pass data of the name so that i can load the data from the database.

the error that i am getting is

```
Cannot resolve method 'get' in 'TextView'

at

intent.putExtra("Name",String.valueOf((holder.Name_id).get(position)));
intent.putExtra("Type",String.valueOf((holder.Type_id).get(position)));
intent.putExtra("Location",String.valueOf((holder.Location_id).get(position)));
```

RecyclerView Adapter

```
public class UserAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UserAdapter.UserHolder>{
    Context context;
    List<Users> usersList;

    public UserAdapter(Context context, List<Users> usersList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.usersList = usersList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public UserHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View userLayout= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_list,parent,false);
        return new UserHolder(userLayout);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull UserHolder holder, int position) {
        Users users=usersList.get(position);
        holder.Name_id.setText(users.getName());
        holder.Type_id.setText(users.getType());
        holder.Location_id.setText(users.getLocation());
        holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, cardviewclick.class);
                intent.putExtra("Name",String.valueOf((holder.Name_id).get(position)));
                intent.putExtra("Type",String.valueOf((holder.Type_id).get(position)));
                intent.putExtra("Location",String.valueOf((holder.Location_id).get(position)));

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return usersList.size();
    }

    public class UserHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView Name_id,Type_id,Location_id;
        CardView cardView;

        public UserHolder(@NonNull View itemView){
            super(itemView);
            Name_id=itemView.findViewById(R.id.textTitle);
            Type_id=itemView.findViewById(R.id.textType);
            Location_id=itemView.findViewById(R.id.textLocation);
            cardView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.card);
        }
    }

}
```

card xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card"
        app:cardElevation="12dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="16dp"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#efefef"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    style="bold"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Title:"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="24dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textTitle"
                    style="bold"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="24dp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    style="bold"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Type:"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="24dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textType"
                    style="bold"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="24dp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    style="bold"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Location:"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="24dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textLocation"
                    style="bold"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="24dp" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error over here:

```java
Cannot resolve method 'get' in 'TextView'

at

intent.putExtra("Name",String.valueOf((holder.Name_id).get(position)));
intent.putExtra("Type",String.valueOf((holder.Type_id).get(position)));
intent.putExtra("Location",String.valueOf((holder.Location_id).get(position)));
```

Tells the whole story, just replace it with:

```java
intent.putExtra("Name",holder.Name_id.getText());
intent.putExtra("Type",holder.Type_id.getText());
intent.putExtra("Location",holder.Location_id.getText());
```

This way, you would get the text inside of them.

All you have to do is to write the correct method since `#get()` doesn't exist.

Comment: maybe you tell me the correct method?

Comment: @LucK I did, I even told you what to replace in your code. Please read my code again.